# How can I recommend one kind of content to a user, based on their liked pages from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to create a small recommendation system based on what pages people like in Facebook. This is how it will work:

- someone will login with Facebook
- accept the terms to retrieve information
- then the program should get all pages this user liked

**Concern**

Since I have all the liked pages from a user, which page should be the most relevant for recommendation?

I was trying the **Graph API Explorer** from Facebook to get all my likes or even comments made to posts of a page that I liked, so with that I could count and prioritise the pages in my program.

However I thought this should be a security issue and after testing I confirmed that was not working (user access tokens permissions were selected correctly for this test).

**Questions**

Is there a way to make this work?
Should I use another solution?

Comment: You won’t be able to get “all” likes or comments the user made on different pages. Apart from that the API has no way to easily select only those out of a page’s feed, it is also not so good on “historical” data – the more back in time you go, the more sparse results will get.

Comment: So don’t try and “prioritize” pages the user likes; rather take _all_ of them into account. If I like bands A, B and C and/or sports teams D, E and F - then suggest other band or sports team pages to me, based on what other users of the app that liked those too also have in their list of liked pages.

Comment: I was starting to consider what you said as a solution. Will try that and it should work. Thanks for the answer!